# jquery autocomplete in partial view not showing results

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

**JQuery Code:**
jquery is in partial view that doesn't have references. References are in master page where this partial is being loaded into a div.
    {
    $("#memberName").autocomplete({

```
            source: function (request, response) {
                //debugger;
                response(callAjax(request.term));
            }
        });

        function callAjax(e) {

            var UserNamelist = [];
            var st = e;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/MasterType/getUserNameList',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { ID: e },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        UserNamelist.push(data[i]);
                    }
                    return UserNamelist;
                },
                error: function (da) {
                    debugger;
                    alert("error In To Users List");
                }
            });
            return UserNamelist;
        }
}
**c# :**

 var res = (from u in udb.UserProfiles
                           where u.DisplayName.StartsWith(ID) && u.ProfilePicture != null
                           select u.DisplayName).Take(10).ToList();

                return Json(res , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

res also put into a proper list and returned.

- **REsult:**
      perfect data is returning into jquery successfully.

  ***But popup is NOT poping out at the bottom of the textbox.***
      If used the 
      source: ["Test Value 1", "Test Value 2", "Test Value 3", "Unique Value"]
      Works perfectly.
      Not sure, but wasted 5 hours in figuring out the cause.

  What could be the reason?

Comment: can you show me the data that is returned from the ajax call?

Comment: Please check this link where i stored the screen shot . http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img661/2842/Kga2BL.jpg

Comment: one more in case first set has a . in one of the record of the data if any doubt that may cause any impact     http://prntscr.com/7tfocd

Comment: After 10 hour work, one small condition to autocomplete solved this problem. It is adding delay: 500. I used async: false but resolved this only after added. Hope somebody else may save the time.